# Ajuda para filtrar arquivo json do firebase no aplicativo

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou construindo um aplicativo que é apenas um filtro de informações que constam no json do database do firebase. Minha dor de cabeça está sendo onde vou aplicar o código de busca! por enquanto está assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String[] setor = {"Modelagem", "Corte", "Silk", "Bordado", "Produção", "Acabamento", "Embalagem", "Lavanderia", "Facção"};
ArrayAdapter<String> Asetor;
Spinner spinner;
Button buscar;
Firebase objetoRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //SPINNER
    Asetor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, setor);
    //PEGANDO ITENS DO SPINNER
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.setor);
    spinner.setAdapter(Asetor);
    //BUTTON BUSCAR
    buscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buscar);

    //FIREBASE
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    objetoRef = new Firebase("https://rastro-4ed10.firebaseio.com/");
    objetoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override //CLASS UTILIZADA PARA ALTERAR UM TEXTVIEW CONFORME O BANCO
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "value is: "+ value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Não sei se faço dentro do onDataChange, ou se faço na Main_Activity onde vai aparecer o resultado...São 3 campos de busca um Spinner e dois EditText.

Comment: Isso vai depender. Se esse filtro for crescer e ficar cada vez mais complexo, aconselho criar uma classe para que receba os dados do `OnDataChange` e retornar onde vai aparecer o resultado. Senão, pode fazer tudo no `onDataChange` mesmo.

Comment: Seria só 3 campos de busca mesmo! Se puder me dar algumas ideias de qual função usar agradeço. "Equals" ?

Comment: Isso vai depender dos campos que você vai trabalhar. Acredito que nesse caso `equals` já seria suficiente porque o retorno é um `String`.